# Question concerning system of equations of complex polynomial equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Let $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ a complex vector, $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_N$ complex matrices and consider the system
$$
a_1 = v^TA_1v \\
a_2 = v^TA_2v \\
\vdots \\
a_N = v^T A_N v
$$
Each equality is a complex polynomial and a solution for each equality exists individually. However, it is not clear to me if a solution to such a system can be found or what are the conditions for a solution to exist.

To simplify life, consider freedom to pick a simple (but non-trivial) vector $v$. Can we derive some conditions that $v$ must satisfy such that a solution exists (even if its hard to find it)?

---

A simple example, in order to illustrate the problem, for $N=2$ gives the system (with $A_1,A_2=A,B$ and $a_1,a_2 = a,b$ and $v=(x\, y)^T$ for simplicity)
$$
0 = A_{11}x^2 + (A_{12}+A_{21})xy + A_{22}y^2 -a = f_a\\
0 = B_{11}x^2 + (B_{12}+B_{21})xy + B_{22}y^2 -b = f_b\\
$$
Recall that $x,y,a,b$ as well as the matrix elements are complex numbers. Therefore we get two complex polynomial equations and essentially we are asking if they intersect.

Is there a way to analyse this completely geometrically and determine if intersection points exist? And can this be generalized for higher $N$?

Comment: You might want to clarify what is fixed and what you are trying to solve for?

Comment: The matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_N$ are fixed ($A,B$ in the example), the vector $v$ can be chosen as wished, the complex numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_N$ ($a,b$ in the example) are fixed and finally we are trying to solve for the entries of the matrices such that the system is satisfied.